# Dimension folder for samsung galaxy s8 plus

Tags: android, android-layout, dimensions

Can anybody help me on what will be the dimension folder to design the screen for **samsung galaxy s8 plus**. It's size and resolution is 6.2-inch; 2,960x1,440 pixels. I am not able to understand the dimension file it's accessing. Currently, I am using [SDP](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) and [SSP](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) for the project. In other devices, application is looking perfect. But in this device screens are totally messed up.

Comment: Whats the DPI for the same device ?

Comment: 529ppi @Lucifer

Comment: ok, can you please put a screenshot for same device in question ?

Comment: Is it possible without watching the screen? Just tell me the dimen folder it's below to.

Comment: You can try using layout-sw529 layout folder.

Comment: @SnehaSarkar did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should put this here into your AndroidManifest under

```
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
```

This is to support larger/other screen sizes like for s8+ or s9+ and other phones.